# Getting all records including non matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following tables

Payment

PayTypeId, Description

- 0 , Credit
- 1, Debit
- 2,Master

ActualPayment
Id,PayTypeId,Amount

- 1,1,10

Here is the output i am looking at

Id,PayTypeId,Amount

- 1,0,NULL
- 1,1,10
- 1,2,NULL

Basically I want all the records of ActualPayment including all payment types.

Here is the query i have used but am not getting any records

```
select
*
from #ActualPayments ap 
left join #Payment p on ap.paytypeid = p.paytypeid 
where p.paytypeid is null
```

Comment: @Randy - A `LEFT JOIN` ***is*** an OUTER join...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one record for each of the three `PayTypeID` values, then you need those three records on the left-hand side of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Equally, if you want the `ActuallPaymentID` on each output line, that value needs to be on the left hand side.

It's all leading you down the wrong avenue with the data that you have, and the tables that you have described.

With just those two tables in your question, I would use this layout instead...

```
SELECT
  ap.ActualPaymentID,
  p.PayTypeID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN ap.PayTypeID = p.PayTypeID THEN ap.Amount END)    AS Amount
FROM
  ActualPayments                    AS ap
CROSS JOIN
  Payment                           AS p
GROUP BY
  ap.ActualPaymentID,
  p.PayTypeID
```

Comment: Updated answer to correct a syntax error : I forgot to put an `END` on the `CASE` statement.

Comment: Dems- your query is perfectly working. Thanks a lot. The other queries I am getting duplicates

Answer (score 2):

You aren't receiving any records because you are filtering everything out with the `WHERE` clause `p.paytypeid is null`

Try running it without the `WHERE` clause.

**Edit:** The below SQL should return the correct information. I've used a `CROSS JOIN` to create an in-line view.  This should remove the unwanted `NULL`s.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.paytypeid, t2.amount
FROM (  
    SELECT id, payment.paytypeid 
    FROM #ActualPayments
    CROSS JOIN #Payment
) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ActualPayments t2 
    ON t1.paytypeid = t2.paytypeid 
;
```

Comment: Still won't work.  Doing exactly as you describe will give 1 record, the OP shows 3 desired output records.

Comment: @Dems you are correct.  I've just tested this and it's because a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is required.

Comment: With a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` the `PayTypeID` is never NULL, but the `ActualPaymentID` IS NULL on two of the rows.  The output still does not match.

Comment: @Dems Correct once again.  I've amended it by using a `CROSS JOIN` to create an in-line view.  It should now work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
select
*
from #ActualPayments ap 
full outer join #Payment p
    on ap.paytypeid = p.paytypeid 
;
```

This will return all rows from the ActualPayments table along with their corresponding values from Payment - if there is any. Additional it will return all rows from Payment for which no ActualPayments exist.
Please note: The where clause of your sample query must not be used!

Comment: Give `NULL`s in the `ap.ID` field (where PayTypeID is 0 or 2).  That does not match the OP's desired output.

Comment: The OPs sample data is most likely bogus at that point. Where should that ID come from?

Comment: OPs Question: `Basically I want all the records of ActualPayment including all payment types.`  Paraphrase of the OP's question: Return one record for every distinct combination of `ActualPaymentID` and `PayTypeID`, including the *(Here I make an assumption; that the ActualPaymentID is not unique)* SUM of the `Amount`s that correspond to each combination.  *[This means that the ActualPaymentID comes from the ActualPayment table, in this case.  See my example answer.]*

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you would want to do this, but here's one way

```
select  ap.Id, pt.PayTypeId, ap2.Amount
from    #ActualPayments ap
    cross join #PaymentTypes pt
    left join #ActualPayments ap2
    on pt.PayTypeId = ap2.PayTypeId
    and ap.Id = ap2.id
```